# Optimize two COUNT/DISTINCT queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with column1 and column2 (both of them contain TEXT). I want to get:

1) the count of unique rows of column1@table, case-insensitive

2) the count of unique rows of column1@table and column2@table, case-insensitive

```
SELECT count(*) AS unique_row1 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT lower(column1) FROM table);

SELECT count(*) AS unique_rows12 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT lower(column1),lower(column1) FROM table);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it? Is there's a way to do it in a one query? I use SQLite3.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit (due to [@ypercube's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966403/974317)):**
Collation was default (case-sensitive, at least I didn't do `COLLATE NOCASE` anywhere).

Also I've made a test and with `COLLATE NOCASE` it's quite faster and the numbers are the same:

```
# time echo "SELECT count(DISTINCT lower(column1)), count(DISTINCT lower(column1 || column2)) FROM table;" | sqlite3 db.sqlite3
1643|5997
echo   0.00s user 0.00s system 25% cpu 0.003 total
sqlite3 db.sqlite3  0.58s user 0.04s system 96% cpu 0.643 total

# time echo "SELECT count(DISTINCT column1), count(DISTINCT column1 || column2) FROM table;" | sqlite3 db.sqlite3              
1658|6199
echo   0.00s user 0.00s system 36% cpu 0.002 total
sqlite3 db.sqlite3  0.42s user 0.04s system 95% cpu 0.483 total

# time echo "SELECT count(DISTINCT column1 COLLATE NOCASE), count(DISTINCT (column1 || column2) COLLATE NOCASE) FROM table;" | sqlite3 db.sqlite3
1643|5997
echo   0.00s user 0.00s system 32% cpu 0.002 total
sqlite3 db.sqlite3  0.43s user 0.04s system 98% cpu 0.481 total
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT column1, column2)` shows an error though: `wrong number of arguments to function count()`, but I hope I've got your idea.

Comment: *row1* and *row2* are **rows** or **columns**?

Comment: I'm very sorry. Of course they are columns. Edited.

Comment: I guess `COUNT(DISTINCT column1, column2)` not working is an SQLite limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT count(distinct lower(column1))
  FROM table
```

And for the second:

```
SELECT count(distinct lower(column1 || column2))
  FROM table
```

Note: In this second case you must use coalesce if your columns can be nulls.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's 4x times faster!

Comment: @IOXenus: Do you get different result if you use: `SELECT count(distinct column1) FROM table` ?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, because that column has the same values, but with different case.

Comment: What is the collation of the table/columns?

Answer (score 1):

I think that text comparisons are by default case-insensitive. Does this work?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1)
     , COUNT(DISTINCT column1, column2)
FROM table
```

Comment: I edited the post for the more capacious reply, but in short - no, it didn't work (with default collation); also I need it in mixed cases sometimes, so setting `COLLATE NOCASE` won't do the thing either. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault, I wasn't familiar with `SELECT` / `COLLATE` syntax. Thanks a lot!